# ASP.NET Core input tag inside tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a form that has multiple fields, that each can take multiple inputs (based on this question add multiple tags to form in net core 3.1 mvc)

Currently it looks like this

```
<input type="text" class="multiple-input form-control text-right" id="teams-input" container-name="teams-container">
                <div class="row justify-content-end" >
                    <div id="teams-container" class="col-md-12 multiple-input-container" input-name="teams-hidden"></div>
                </div>
                <input asp-for="Teams" type="hidden" id="teams-hidden"/>
```

I use tag helper to reuse this code

```
[HtmlTargetElement("multi-input")]
public class MultipleInputsTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(@$"<input type='text' class='multiple-input form-control text-right' id='{Name}-input' container-name='{Name}-container'>
            <div class='row justify-content-end' >
                <div id='{Name}-container' class='col-md-12 multiple-input-container' input-name='{Name}-hidden'></div>
            </div>
            <input asp-for='{For.Name}' type='hidden' id='teams-hidden' />");
    }
}
```

Tag helper is used in form like this

```
<multi-input asp-for="Teams" asp-name="teams"></multi-input>
```

I need for hidden input inside multi-input tag to map to model's Teams property, but after tag processing hidden input looks like this in browser

```
<input asp-for="Teams" type="hidden" id="teams-hidden">
```

And doesn't map to model's property

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need firstly know that `asp-for` tag helper will generate the id and name element in frontend(refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-input-tag-helper)), and it will bind the property value by default.

Your code just generates the `asp-for` element, `asp-for` tag helper does not work any more, you need refer to the [tag helper source code here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/04ce6cae44fb0cb11470c21769d41e3f8088e8aa/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/InputTagHelper.cs#L361) to learn how to custom tag helper.

Change your code like below:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("multi-input")]
public class MultipleInputsTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private readonly IHtmlGenerator _generator;
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public MultipleInputsTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator)
    {
        _generator = generator;
    }
    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            writer.Write(@$"<input type='text' class='multiple-input form-control text-right' id='{Name}-input' container-name='{Name}-container'>
        <div class='row justify-content-end' ><div id='{Name}-container' class='col-md-12 multiple-input-container' input-name='{Name}-hidden'></div>
        </div>");               
            
            //here is the importance.....
            //for how to generate and bind the property data 
            var textArea = _generator.GenerateTextBox(ViewContext,
                                For.ModelExplorer,
                                For.Name,
                                For.Model,
                                null,
                                new { @type = "hidden",@id= "teams-hidden" });

            textArea.WriteTo(writer, NullHtmlEncoder.Default);               
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent(writer.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```